# Unable to copy database file to other foulder

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, copy

I am using following code to copying database file to other folder just to make temporary writing file.

```
BOOL success;
NSArray*dirPath;
NSString*docDir;
NSString*databasePath;
NSString*databaseName=@"EXPENSES";

//path for database
dirPath=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docDir=[dirPath objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath=[docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

NSLog(@" docDir %@",docDir);
//check if present
NSFileManager*fm=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
success=[fm fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

if(success)
{
    NSLog(@"DATA BASE Already present");
}
else
{

    //Copy from bundle to DocumentsDirectory on first run. Where DB won't be available in DocumentsDirectory.
    NSString*bundlePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"EXPENSES" ofType:@""];
    NSError*error;
    success=[fm copyItemAtPath:bundlePath toPath:databasePath error:&error];

    if(success)
    {
        NSLog(@"DATA BASE Created successfully");
    }

} // End of else when DB not present in documents directory.
```

But the file is not copying instead app is crashing with error "reason: '*** -[NSFileManager copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:]: source path is nil'" please help me to debug the code Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing two mistakes here.

1. You didn't mentioned your destination file extension

   Instead of `NSString*databaseName=@"EXPENSES";`

   Use `NSString*databaseName=@"EXPENSES.sqlite";`
2. This code is the actual issue:

   ```
   NSString*bundlePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"EXPENSES" ofType:@""];
   ```

Here you are telling to `NSFileManager` that find the file with name `"EXPENSES"` and it's extension is `""` probably there will be no file with these criteria. So the source path'll be `nil`. That's why the application is crashing.

Usually the extension of database file will be `sqlite`. Replace your code like:

```
NSString*bundlePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"EXPENSES" ofType:@"sqlite"];
```

Comment: I have not mentioned any extension, Before it was working but i dont know what happend suddenly its not working now

Comment: @Deepak: please check that the file is still in main bundle

Comment: Thank for quick reply . Its still there in main bundle.

Comment: I as you suggested I  have added extensions also but didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the bundle database extension for ofType in:
 `NSString*bundlePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"EXPENSES" ofType:@"<extension>"];` The error suggests inability to find the specified file.

Comment: I have not mentioned any extension, Before it was working but i dont know what happend suddenly its not working now

Comment: NSLog the paths and check for file existence as well as filenames. If it was working previously, there's no reason why it should stop working abruptly.

Comment: Thank for the quick reply . Now I found bundlePath is giving null. What is problem with this.(What does it mean)

Comment: it means the system cannot find the path to that particular file. did you try adding the db extension ?

Comment: yes tried. I am getting database path but getting bundel path as null.Does it mean it's not getting copy at all.

Comment: seems like your file isnt present in your app bundle. Check your project's file explorer for the file. have you added the DB to your project the way you add images etc ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20561/discussion-between-kevin-and-deepak)

Answer (score 0):

I have come out of that problem. I dont know what logic behind it , I just exported fresh data base from SVN and added to my project bundle its working perfectly fine